# Remove delete button from the first row and start the button from the second row

Tags: html, laravel

I want to remove delete button on first edit row.  I need to start delete button from the second row. How can I do that? Does Anyone have any idea? Please help me. Thanks.

[image]

**Html view**

```
<div class="row addmore_issues">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if (count($issues) > 0)
            @foreach ($issues as $key => $details)
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden"  value="{{$details->id}}"  name="id[]" >
                            <input required type="date" value="{{$details->date}}" name="date[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input required type="text"  value="{{$details->issue}}"  name="issue[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 mt12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm delete">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="id[]" class="form-control" >
                        <input required type="date" value="" name="date[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input required type="text"  value=""  name="issue[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$loop->first` to get the first iteration. so use a if condition with [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable) to remove delete button from the first row.

```
@foreach ($issues as $key => $details)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden"  value="{{$details->id}}"  name="id[]" >
                <input required type="date" value="{{$details->date}}" name="date[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input required type="text"  value="{{$details->issue}}"  name="issue[]" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (!$loop->first)
            <div class="col-md-1 mt12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```